# Transforming a Xml file using Xslt based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Looking for a way to transform an xml using xlst based on predefined values

I am very new to xslt, please pardon me, if this is a basic question.

**Input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

  <project groups="mygroup" name="test1/project1" path="current_dir" />
  <project groups="mygroup" name="test2/project2" path="some_dir/foo"/>
  <project groups="mygroup" name="test3/project3" path="new_dir/bar"/>
  <project groups="mygroup" name="test4/project4" path="current_dir/baz"/>

</manifest>
```

**Looking for a output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest>
    
      <project groups="mygroup" name="test1/project1" path="myfolder" />
      <project groups="mygroup" name="test2/project2" path="myfolder/step1"/>
      <project groups="mygroup" name="test3/project3" path="test_folder/>      
    </manifest>
```

Basically, change the path to a predefined custom path and exclude the lines that does not have a custom path.

```
if name="test1/project1" change path="myfolder"
if name="test2/project2" change path="myfolder/step1"
if name="test3/project3" change path="test_folder"
```

remove line for everything else

I started with the below code, but this one modifies path to same one ( considering that there are no conditional checks ).
I would like to add conditions to check for "name" attribute, and change the "path" attribute to a corresponding path, and also drop for which a custom path is not needed. For example test4/project4 in the above example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/manifest/project/@path">
    <xsl:attribute name="path">Custom Path</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact rules the stylesheet should follow when modifying the value of the `path` attribute.

Comment: @yitzhak-khabinsky I am stuck at matching the exact attribute, checking this further will update the question, if I get more ideas on improving the example.

Comment: I am using xsltproc tool for the conversion, I think any XSLT standard may work.

Comment: @michael.hor257k added some edits, does it address your comment ?

Comment: The rules that you have added will not produce the output you show.

Comment: Fixed the question

Comment: @michael.hor257k version should work 

Comment: Yes, the new version produces the output I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The rules you have posted are not clear. The output you show *could* be produced using the following stylesheet - but I am not certain that provides a true answer to your question.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test1/project1'">
             <project groups="{@groups}" name="test1/project1" path="myfolder" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test2/project2'">
             <project groups="{@groups}" name="test2/project2" path="myfolder/step1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test3/project3'">
             <project groups="{@groups}" name="test3/project3" path="test_folder" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> Is it possible to change only the "path" attribute instead of repeating the other attributes ? I ask this because, there is a possibility that the input xml may get appended with other attributes over time

It is not possible to "change only the `path` attribute" because you also want to remove the parent `project` element altogether when none of the tests return true. However, it *is* possible to copy all the **other** attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test1/project1'">
             <project path="myfolder">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')] "/>
             </project>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test2/project2'">
             <project path="myfolder/step1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')] "/>
             </project>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@name='test3/project3'">
             <project path="test_folder" >
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')] "/>
             </project>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect.!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Is it possible to change only the "path" attribute instead of repeating the other attributes ?  I ask this because, there is a possibility that the input xml may get appended with other attributes over time

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run through the "project" nodes and check the corresponding queries via "if" and write the change if there is a hit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <manifest>
          <xsl:for-each select="//manifest/project">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="@name='test1/project1'">
                    <project path="myfolder">
                         <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')]"/>
                    </project>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="@name='test2/project2'">
                    <project path="myfolder/step1">
                         <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')]"/>
                    </project>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="@name='test3/project3'">
                    <project path="test_folder">
                         <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='path')]"/>
                    </project>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- Otherwise To Nothing -->
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
     </manifest>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also have a look at the reference:

- xslt:for-each  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_for_each.asp
- xlst:if  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_if.asp

Comment: Thank you, @andreas-hauser. Yes. This solution worked too.  As in my other comment,  which I had not made it clear in the question.. is it possible to just change the "path" attribute after matching and keep all other attributes in the line intact? There is a possibility of additional attributes to be added in the future

Comment: Of course, therefore you just need to take the current "project"-node in the if-condition and change only the value form the "path"-attribute.

Comment: For mutually exclusive alternatives, `xsl:choose` is preferred over multiple `xsl:if` instructions. It saves redundant evaluations after a true case has been found.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you are right, especially when large amounts of data have to be processed.